QML check the type of a property at runtime
I am trying to check the type of a property at runtime:
Node {
    id: root

    property string foo
    property color diffuseColor
    ...
}

(because I am setting it dynamically from a JS object like {foo: "bar", diffuseColor: [0.5, 1, 0]} only that colors are given in an incompatible format, so a simple assignment would not work.
I need code like:
var targetObject = ... // the QML object
for(var k in jsobj) {
    if(isColorProperty(targetObject[k]))
        targetObject[k] = Qt.rgba(jsobj[k][0], jsobj[k][1], jsobj[k][2], 1)
    else
        targetObject[k] = jsobj[k]
}

to implement that isColorProperty() I tried many different approaches, such as using instanceof (type error), checking Object.getPrototypeOf result (type error), using .toString() (only returns an HTML color string), 'typeof' (returns 'object') none of those worked.

Howabout function isColorProperty(c) { return Qt.color(c) === c }  ?

Why don't you just use Qt.rgba for the jsobj construction? You should be able to use Qt.rgba inside a JavaScript file.

Solution is to use pragma ValueTypeBehavior: Addressable.
With this pragma, amongst other things, it is possible to check value types with instanceof, e.g.:
root.foo instanceof color // true

